# Why is ^M being added to a script.r after modifying with Meld?

Tags: linux, dos, carriage-return, meld

Esteemed Meld and Emacs/ESS users,

What I did:

1. Create a script.r using Emacs/ESS.
2. Make some modifications to script.r by pulling some lines of code from another_script.r
3. Reopen another_script.r (or script.r) in Emacs/ESS to continue working.

All the lines in another_script.r which were *not* pushed to script.r end with ^M

Some times it's the other way around - only the line that was pushed/pulled ends with ^M's. So far i haven't isolated exactly which action determines where the ^M's are placed. Either way i still end up with ^M's all over the place and i'd like to avoid getting them after using Meld!

FWIW: the directory is being synced by Dropbox; in Meld, Preferences > Encoding tab, "utf8" is entered in the text box; all actions are performed under Linux (Ubunt 12.04) with Meld v1.5.3, Emacs v23.3.1

Current workaround is running in a terminal: `dos2unix /path/to/script.r` which strips the `^M`s. But this shouldn't be necessary and I'm hoping some one here can tell me how to avoid these.

Cheers.

Comment: This doesn't look like an R issue. Perhaps you should post this on a Meld/Git forum after identifying which tool introduces that (by eliminating one at a time from your steps)

Comment: @A_K I agree this likely has nothing to do with R- the R tag was flippant. But stackoverflow has returned 90% of all my git google searches hitherto including ones related to `^M`, hence my starting point here.

Comment: How is this off topic? The site scope explicitly includes "software tools commonly used by programmers" such as Git and Meld.

Comment: @Mechanical_snail Indeed I too was vexed as how Meld/Git issues are off topic here. Nevertheless it seems Meld alone is the culprit and have edited the question accordingly, as well as posting on the [Meld mailing list](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/meld-list/2012-December/thread.html). Will repost & link any useful replies.

Comment: how Git is in game here? I can't see any mention of it.

Comment: @Lazy_Badger Git tag removed - thanks for pointing this out. Having investigated a little further myself, Git has nothing to do with the issue. It appears to be Meld alone or Meld/Emacs issue. Oh that's something else i can & will check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a terminal i ran `cat script.r | hexdump -C | head` and amongst the output returned found a `0d 0a`, which is DOS formatting for a new line (carriage return `0d` immediately followed by a line feed `0a`). I ran the same command on another_script.r i was merging with but only observed `0a`, no `0d 0a`, indicating Unix formatting.

To check further if this was the source of the ^M line endings, script.r was converted to unix formatting via `dos2unix script.r` & verified that `0d 0a` was converted to `0a` using hexdump -C as above. I performed a merge using Meld in attempting to replicate the process which yielded ^M line endings in my script's. I re-oppened both files in Emacs/ESS and found no ^M line endings. Short of converting script.r *back* to dos formatting and repeating the above procedure to see if the ^M line endings re-appear, i believe i've solved my ^M issue, which simply is that, unbeknownst to me, one of my files was dos formatted. My take home message: in a Windows dominated environ, never assume that one's personal linux environment doesn't contain DOS bits. Or line endings.